# angular 5 : how to know my map is loaded correctly inside constructor of all components?

Tags: typescript, angular5, openlayers-3

I have a mapservice(**maps.service.ts**) , in which I've wrote some code for loading the map , like this ,

```
loadMap(target: string, extent?: number[], proj?: string) {
      var self = this;
      this._mapExtent = !extent ? [372728.74434305, 2677793.4448, 378257.6623, 2682126.61080438] : extent;
      this.projection = proj || this.projection;

      this._map = new OlMap({
        layers: [
          new OlTileLayer({
            source: new olSourceOSM()
          }),
          //  layerWFS
        ],
        target: target,            
        view: new OlView({
          center: this._mapExtent,
          projection: this.projection,
          maxZoom: 19,
          zoom: 13
        })
      });

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._map.once('postrender', function (map) {
          self.isMapLoaded = true;
          resolve(map);
        })
      });
      //return this._map.once('postrender').map(res => res.json());
    }
```

and a `getMap()` method to get map instance throughout the app ,

```
getMap() {
          return this._map;
        }
```

But in another controller , inside the constructor , I need to subscribe map change event , like this ,

```
constructor(){
  self.mapService.getMap().on('moveend', (evt) => {
      if (self.undoRedo === false) {
        if (self.size < self.navHistory.length - 1) {
          for (var i = self.navHistory.length - 1; i > self.size; i--) {
            self.navHistory.pop();
          }
        }
        self.navHistory.push({
          extent: self.mapService.getMap().getView().calculateExtent(self.mapService.getMap().getSize()),
          size: self.mapService.getMap().getSize(),
          zoom: self.mapService.getMap().getView().getZoom()
        });
        self.size = self.size + 1;
      }

    });
}
```

but the problem is , constructor is loading before map loaded and `map` is getting `undefined` , could anyone please suggest a best practice for this scenario? do i need to make getMap() method to return promise and call getMap().then() always ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: When the constructor is called, there are no visible components yet. Thats why "map" is undefined. Look at the [OnInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit) hook. That's where you want to do these kind of things. Depending on how you implemented everything you might have a chance using [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables). Basically your getMap should return an Observable and your controller subscribes to it in its constructor. Something like:

```
constructor(){
  self.mapService.getMap()
    .subscribe(map => map.on('moveend', (evt) => {
      //your code here
      }))
}
```

On a more general note: Why are you wrapping a visible component into a service? Services are not meant for that. You should probably look into creating a Map-Component that wraps OL.